# Spring Integration Inbound File Adaptor not deleting Local file from the directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, integration

I want to poll a local directory and send that message (File) to a sftp location.
I have been able to send the message to the sftp location successfully, but Spring Integration file adaptor is not deleting the source file.  How do I make the spring integration file inbound adapter delete the local source file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such an option on a File Inbound Channel Adapter since we cannot remove files unconditionally - their content might be required downstream which may happen on a fully different thread from the poller.

We recommend to use a simple `File.delete()` execution as a service activator logic downstream the SFTP transferring channel adapter.

It might be even better to have a `PublishSubscribeChannel` as an input for your `SftpMessageHandler` subscriber and add another one as plain as this:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public void deleteLocalFile(File payload) {   
   payload.delete();
}
```

Comment: Yup, that worked

Comment: For the even better option with PublishSubscribeChannel - what if SFTP file transfer failed and I'd want to retry? I guess it won't be possible if another subscriber has already deleted the file, or am I missing smth?

Comment: If you don't use an `Executor` on that `PublishSubscribeChannel` and the first subscriber is your SFTP file transfer, and it fails, then removal subscriber is not going to be called. You indeed can use a retry on that first subscriber, but it has to be blocking to not return a control to the `PublishSubscribeChannel` to move onto the second subscriber.